# How to get twitter followers list with follower count greater than a value?

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-follow

Twitter API -> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=dogecoin&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=true

returns list of followers and their entities but is there any way to get list of only those followers who have certain number follower threshold value?

I am trying to get list of followers for a particular user but of only those followers who have more than 50k followers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in the Twitter API, no.

Answer (score 0):

With your target twitter account, you could :

- in a loop: get followers'ids with [GET followers/ids](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-ids) (up to 5000 by each request).
- in another loop: get information for each id with [GET users/lookup](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup) (up to 100 ids by request)
- And filter on users having followers_count >= 50k